# Set color for VS 2022 Pro Javascript Class

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I would like to change the color of classes in the text editor of Visual Studio 2022 for a Javascript project. Where can I make this change?

I was hoping to make it look more like VS code to the right (Green).

[image]

I thought it may be in the font and colors, but the class color is not reflective of the experience as you can see below.

[image: Jams Mapper is a Class, so why is it blue?]

I was able to confirm that vs recognizes it as a class.
[image]